# PayPal, IPN and a secure downloads page

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have setup a PayPal button, enabled IPN and set up an IPN listener page that verifies the payment was completed and sends an email with a link to a secure download page that expires in 30 days (AWS S3 expiring url).

It all works great, as long as they get my email.

I would like to also have the IPN listener page display my secure download link, but don't see how to keep anyone from just hitting the IPN listener page anytime they want and generating a new download link.

I was going to use session variables, set on on the listener page, then redirect to another page where I would display the secure link. On that page I would check that the session variable was set after the payment was completed, but session variables don't work with the IPN process as it is 2 different sessions. the session doing the verification is server to server, the page the buyer sees is not in the same session.

How can I display a download link but know that the page displaying it was only accessed after a completed payment? is there something like a referrer url I could check? since they are sent to that page by paypal, it seems like I should be able to check that, but I don't know how.

I am using C# in a very simple webforms project. I am not using a database.

Comment: If the 'IPN listener page' verifies that the payment took place, how can anybody else hit it fraudently?.

Comment: the listener page url is visible if you view the code of the paypal button. Anyone can end up on it if they know where to look for it. The listener page doesn't know if it is verified or not until it gets the data from PP and checks it, but that process is server to server and you can't access the info in the session the buyer sees. If the listener url was not in the button html it probably wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It looks like you should be able to set the listener page url without it being in the button html, but when I tried that (it is a setting in the Sellers setup) it didn't work. I currently have it set in the settings and in the button as both return url and notify_url.

Comment: If by 'listener URL' you mean the IPN URL configured for the button, again I fail to see the problem. That URL should be accessible for POSTS only, and only from PayPal hosts, and it is required to execute aPayPal verification callback, which external users will certainly fail even if they get past the POST issue, which they can't if you configure the resource correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I had this setup was incorrect. After reading EJP's comment I went back and looked at my setup. I had the Return URL and the Notify_url as the same, both going to the IPN listener. I also had these in the buttons HTML code where they were visible.

The Notify_url is for the IPN listener only. This is server to server, and is where I generate the email with the download link.

The Return url is where PayPal takes the user after the transaction - returning them to your site. If you use rm=2 as an advanced variable when creating the button, then PayPal will POST the same info to the Return url as it does to the IPN listener page (at least so far that is what I see).

Using the POST data you can check that it was a transaction from PayPal, and then run code to display a secure download link on the Return url. If someone comes across the page they won't see anything.

Initially when I was testing things the button creation part didn't work so well, and I ended up putting the different hidden inputs in the buttons html, and also set everything to the same url - I wasn't sure what the difference between notify and return was, and this is where I went astray.